# How generalize classes and access properties?

Tags: c#, oop

I want to generalize a class `A` and create an object of class `A` having properties of class `A` and `B`. This is the code I have done but I am not able to access properties in `B`, only `A` type properties are accessible. How to do it?

And please tell me what this concept is called (`A test = new B();`)

```
Class Programe
{
    Main()
    {
        A test = new B();
    }
}

Class A
{
    int aint;
}

Class B:A
{
    int bint;
}

Class test:A
{
    int testint;
}
```

Comment: Why `A test = new B();`? and not `B test = new B();`?

Comment: And what do you mean with `Class test:A` bit? If `A`, `B` and `test` are classes, then `A test = new B();` does not make sense ...

Comment: If you post code, make sure it compiles or at least it's clear why it doesn't compile; `Class` but certainly `Clas` is not c#.

Comment: Thanks all for reply , smartdev I need to get the reference of b in a and jeroen I dont know how to make it in code section so pasted it in html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is called inheritance.

```
A test = new B();
B bReference = test as B;
System.Console.WriteLine(bReference.bint);
```

with `new B()` you create an instance of class `B` and save the reference to it in the variable test. The variable `test` is a variable that can hold references to instances of class `A`. `B` is a subclass of `A`, so your new instance can be treated like an instance of `A`, so it is possible to store it in your variable `test`.
If you want to access your instance's members, which are specific to `B`, you have to treat your reference as a reference to an instance of `B`. You can do that by using the `as` operator.

Comment: Thanks this is working ! but i need to avoid the reference is there any other way that the test it self gets reference of b object without casting it with as b

Comment: you cannot change test to become a reference to a B instance. But you can do the following if you want to keep it inline: ((B)test).bint or (test as B).bint